# Using EventMachine to make multiple request using same connection?

Tags: ruby, udp, eventmachine, em-http-request

I have an EventMachine running that is listening for UDP packets. Every time a UDP packet is received, I would like to forward the data to some database using a REST call. I have created an EM::Connection subclass in which the `receive_data` method forwards the data through a REST call.

Since the frequency of data is quite high, I would like to reuse the connection between requests (using "keep-alive") and if possible also use pipelining. What would be a good way to share the connection between different calls?

Currently my UDPHandler looks something like the following:

```
module Udp
  module Collector
    class UDPHandler < EM::Connection
      def receive_data(data)
        http = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new('http://databaseurl.com/').post body: data
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This class is called as follows:

```
EM.run do
  EM.open_datagram_socket('0.0.0.0', 9000, Udp::Collector::UDPHandler)
end
```

I thought of making the request object a class variable but I don't think that is a good idea in the context of eventmachines. Or is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe something like this should work

```
module Udp
  module Collector
    class UDPHandler < EM::Connection
      def http_connection
        @http_connection ||= EventMachine::HttpRequest.new('http://databaseurl.com/')
      end

      def receive_data(data)
        http = http_connection.post body: data, keepalive: true
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But you can't execute parallel request in this manner, so you need to use some kind of connection pool.

The most simplest one without queueing and other stuff is:

```
module Udp
  module Collector
    class UDPHandler < EM::Connection
      def connection_pool
        @connection_pool ||= []
      end

      def get_connection
        conn = connection_pool.shift
        conn ||= EventMachine::HttpRequest.new('http://databaseurl.com/')
        conn
      end

      def receive_data(data)
        conn = get_connection
        request = conn.post body: data, keepalive: true
        request.callback do
          connection_pool << conn
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```